# jQuery .ajax POST request has an empty body when received by Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

For some reason when I make an ajax post using jQuery, the body, as received by node is empty.  Here is my ajax post:

**jQuery**

```
var formData = {
    'order': order,
    'words': 'words'
};

$.ajax({

    type: 'post',

    url: 'https://example.com/charge',    
    processData: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(formData),

    contentType: 'json', 

    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: false
    },  

    headers: {

    }, 

    success: function (data) {
        console.log('Success');
        console.log(data);

    },  

    error: function () {
        console.log('We are sorry but our servers are having an issue right now');
    }
})
```

And here is my node code:

**Node**

`app.js`

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use('/', routes);
```

`routes/index.js`

```
router.post('/charge', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
} //This always logs {}
```

I have no idea what  I could be doing wrong here. My browser even shows a payload and the post request (the `formData` object) but node logs nothing.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ajax request like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'https://example.com/charge',   
    data: formData,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: false
    },  
    headers: {

    }, 
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('Success');
        console.log(data);
    },  
    error: function () {
        console.log('We are sorry but our servers are having an issue right now');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Mine was not working too, but solved by using,

```
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify(formdata),
```

Answer (score 1):

Check following api

**By setting the processData option to false, the automatic conversion of data to strings is prevented.**

If you want to use json type, processData must be setted true

[Jquery processData](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#example-2)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a late reply, but please also note the JQuery ajax documentation:

> Object must be Key/Value pairs.

This took me 2 hours (server received empty body) because I was trying to post a more 'complicated' object.

Comment: I was going nuts trying to figure mine out - I was doing all the right things except the object that I was building up to pass in was an array. I ended up changing my initialisation of the object from `var data = []` to `var data = {}` and everything was good. Beware array vs. object.